# What's wrong with this simple OpenGL/JOGL stencil test?

Tags: opengl, jogl, stencil-buffer

I'm learning how to use a stencil buffer, but so far have been unsuccessful at getting a even a simple example to work.  In fact, despite trying various combinations of parameters for `glStencilOp` and `glStencilFunc` I have not been able to see any evidence that the stencil buffer is working at all.  I'm starting to suspect my graphics driver (Mac Pro, Mac OS X 10.8.5) or JOGL (2.0.2) doesn't support it... or I'm missing something really basic.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

I'm expecting to see the red diamond clipped by the green diamond.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault();
        final GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
        final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(glcapabilities);
        final GLU glu = new GLU();

        glcanvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {}



            @Override
            public void init(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
                GL2 gl = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();

                glcapabilities.setStencilBits(8);

                gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_PROJECTION);
                gl.glLoadIdentity();

                glu.gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 10000);
                glu.gluLookAt(0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

                gl.glMatrixMode(GLMatrixFunc.GL_MODELVIEW);
                gl.glLoadIdentity();
            }



            @Override
            public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {}



            @Override
            public void display(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
                GL2 gl = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();

                gl.glEnable(GL.GL_STENCIL_TEST);

                gl.glClearStencil(0x0);
                gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

                gl.glStencilFunc(GL.GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
                gl.glStencilOp(GL.GL_REPLACE, GL.GL_REPLACE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
            gl.glStencilMask(0xFF);
                //gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
                //gl.glDepthMask(false);

                gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
                gl.glVertex2f(-25.0f, 0.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(0.0f, 15.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(25.0f, 0.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(0.0f, -15.0f);
                gl.glEnd();

            gl.glStencilMask(0);
                gl.glStencilFunc(GL2.GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
                gl.glStencilOp(GL2.GL_KEEP, GL2.GL_KEEP, GL2.GL_KEEP);
                //gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
                //gl.glDepthMask(true);

                gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
                gl.glVertex2f(-20.0f, 0.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(0.0f, 20.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(20.0f, 0.0f);
                gl.glVertex2f(0.0f, -20.0f);
                gl.glEnd();
            }
        });

        final JFrame jframe = new JFrame("One Triangle Swing GLCanvas");
        jframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowevent) {
                jframe.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        jframe.getContentPane().add(glcanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.setSize(640, 480);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a call to glStencilMask() which does the stenciling. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer

Comment: @zero298 I tried it with and without `glStencilMask`.  I added it to my example above, which still produces the same image.

Comment: Try my new edit.  After copying and pasting your code, changing capabilities worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a call to `glStencilMask()` it's what controls what gets written or not.  Set it to do or don't write, draw a stencil (in your case, the diamond), set the `glStencilMask()` again, and then draw what you want to get clipped.

This has a good sample: [Stencil Buffer explanation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer)

**EDIT:**

OK, I think I found the problem.  You need to set your capabilities up at the top of the program.

```
final GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
glcapabilities.setStencilBits(8);
final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(glcapabilities);
```

The important part being:
**`glcapabilities.setStencilBits(8);`**

[image: My clipped output]

Thanks to: [enabling stencil in jogl](http://chrisingradschool.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/enabling-the-stencil-buffer-in-jogl-opengl-java/)

Comment: I would be very happy if that was the solution, but I've already tried it with no luck.  See my above edited example.  I get the same result.

Comment: @whiskeyspider: Just because you added that line to your code does not mean you did it properly. You need to set the capabilities _before_ creating a render context. In other words, before `final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(glcapabilities);`.

Answer (score 4):

Zero298 has the right idea, though fails to explain why what you tried in your code does not work. This becomes more apparent when you understand how framebuffer pixel formats work in OpenGL; I will touch on this a little bit below, but first just to re-hash the proper solution:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GLProfile      glprofile      = GLProfile.getDefault ();
    GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities   (glprofile);

    // You must do this _BEFORE_ creating a render context
    glcapabilities.setStencilBits (8);

    final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas (glcapabilities);
    final GLU      glu      = new GLU      ();
```

The important thing is that you do this before creating your render context ("canvas"). The stencil buffer is not something you can enable or disable whenever you need it -- you first have to select a pixel format that reserves storage for it. Since pixel formats are fixed from the time you create your render context onward, you need to do this before `new GLCanvas (...)`.

You can actually use an FBO to do stencil operations in a render context that does not have a stencil buffer, but this is much more advanced than you should be considering at the moment. Something to consider if you ever want to do MSAA though, FBOs are a much nicer way of changing pixel formats at run-time than creating and destroying your render context ("canvas").

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing this out.  I was scratching my head at @zero298's answer, since in fact, I did have `glcapabilities.setStencilBits(8)` in my init method already.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't notice that glCapabilities was already in the code.  I just saw that it wasn't and knew that was an issue.  Next time I'll be sure to explain why something works.